# Bootstrap Navbar mobile screen menu is not working on wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am converting a bootstrap theme to wordpress. everything is working fine now without the menu button of the navbar in mobile/small screens. i have added the functions as well. i don't know what's wrong. Please help.

**PHP Functions**

```
add_theme_support('menus');
function register_theme_menus(){
    register_nav_menus (array(
        'primary_menu'=>__('Primary Menu','twentysixteen')
    )  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_theme_menus');
```

Comment: Did you link to the Bootstrap .js anywhere? <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes, i did it on function.php